# Using openGL to compute large-by-small matrix multiplication

Tags: opengl-es, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am working on a computation-heavy IOS app and would like to do a matrix multiplication. The dimensions are like (1,000,000-by-6) and (6-by-2) thus it takes the CPU a few hundred ms to compute which is too slow for me. I am looking into openGL for help and find [Bartosz Ciechanowski's samples](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/01/05/exploring_gpgpu_on_ios/) pretty helpful. However, he did not try a vector-by-matrix multiplication, which is what I need.

I have also read some background about openGL, but all tutorials take most of their time into the computer vision stuff so I feel it would me a long time to get through the unrelated things. Any suggestions on where I can find short cuts?